# Correlation between pseudo inverse and almost exact matrix

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse, condition-number

Let say I have 2 matrices (with a large dimensions), V, E.
and
$|V-E|_{2}\approx3\times10^{-11}$
I would expect that $VE^{+}=A$ would be very similar to the identity matrix up till replacement of some 1s in the main diagonals by  0s.
Instead when I calculate it, I do get  1s in the main diagonals, and a lot of non-negligible "noise" in the other cells. in one of the cells of the main diagonal I actually get 0.43...
I do understand that there are some counter-examples of matrices which exhibit some strange phenomena(as it's math) , but I would expect that almost all matrices would be "nice" in the sense they will be very close to the identity matrix (up to 0s switching 1s) when V is almost E. Is it related somehow to condition number?

What do I miss?

Comment: If $|V|_2$ and $|E|_2$ are small relative to $3 \times 10^{-11}$, what you observe is plausible. [But this isn't the only possible reason.]

Comment: @angryavian no, they are much larger than that.